# Delete a list of User Profiles

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, user-profile

(I am a newbie to PS who has mostly used VBS and Batch so I am still working on following PS scripts)

I need to delete most (but not all) domain accounts off of all 500 of our systems.
Some of these are from a specific list.
Some follow a generic format *21, *19, etc...

I can find scripts that will let me delete a specific user account but I can't figure out how to pass it the long list or use the wildcards...

This one seems promising if I can figure out how to get the values need in it...

:: This Script taken from https://www.nextofwindows.com/delete-user-profiles-on-a-remote-computer-in-powershell

---

```
 $Computer = Read-Host "Please Enter Computer Name: "

 $user = Read-Host "Enter User ID: "

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {

param($user)

$localpath = 'c:\users\' + $user

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -eq $localpath} | 

Remove-WmiObject

} -ArgumentList $user
```

---

Comment: It seems like all you need you do is put your conditions into the `Where-Object` braces.

Comment: Yes, but when I have a list of 15 or more profiles that need to be deleted is there a way to pass it a list without hard coding each one specifically?

Comment: Are you deleting multiple accounts from multiple computers?

Comment: Yes.  We have 500 staff PCs and I want to delete all of the contractor, IT Staff, test accounts, etc. from all of the systems.  So in reality I would like to pass the code a list of computers and a list of profile names.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are most of the way there. Just use some pipelines and a foreach loop or two.

This will attempt to remove all users in the list from all computers in the list:

```bsh
# define function that takes user list from pipeline
function Remove-User {
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $user,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $computer
    )
    
    process {
        # copied from question
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | 
                Where-Object { $_.LocalPath -eq "c:\users\${$user}" } |
                    Remove-WmiObject
        } -ArgumentList $user
    }
}

# get your lists whatever way makes sense
$userList = Import-Csv -Path "users.csv" -Delimiter ','
$computerList = Import-Csv -Path "computers.csv" -Delimiter ','

# call function to remove all users for each computer
$computerList | ForEach-Object {
    $userList | Remove-User -computer $_
}
```

I'm not sure where you get your list from, but I used a csv just because.

*note: This is going off the assumption that the `Invoke-Command` portion of code from [nextOfWindows](https://www.nextofwindows.com/delete-user-profiles-on-a-remote-computer-in-powershell) does what it says